# Edit "compile with" library in eclipse

Tags: android

I have an Android project I am working on, and since I start, Google has released API 18 (Android 4.3).  When I initially configured my Android project, I chose to compile my app with API 17.  How can I change the compile API to 18?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use SDK Manager to download the desired API Level, in your case 18.
Then change your AndroidManifest and change target SDK to 18.
And last but not least open your project properties, go to the android section and in the list of SDK select the checkbox at API Level 18.

Now make a clean and rebuild and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by going into the project properties and selecting the `Project Build Target` as shown below

[image]

Or

You can change it from AndroidManifest.xml file, by changing the  `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` to your desired version.

Comment: Simply changing the target version in the Manifest is not enough, you must go to the project properties as you recommended in your screenshot.  Thank you for the help